# Appending to the dictionary dynamically

Tags: python

I am reading from a text file which has the format below:

```
0.000 ff:dd ff:ff 4 126 48000  
0.001 sd:fg er:sd 5 125 67000  
0.002 qw:er ff:dd 5 127 90000  
0.003 xc:sd ff:dd 5 127 90000  
0.004 io:uy gh:ij 4 126 56000
```

In the fourth column, 4 indicates request and 5 indicates response. i should form a dictionary with second column as the key if that row represents a request.
If the fourth column value is 5, it indicates that the row corresponds to the response. In this case, look at the 3rd column of that response, and if that 3rd column is there as the dictionary key, add 2rd column as an value of that corresponding key.

In the above example, the desired result is:

```
{'ff:dd': 1, 2, 48000, qw:er, xc:sd}, {'io:uv': 1, 0, 56000}
```

For ff:dd, 1 indicates that there is only 1 request from the ff:dd; 2 indicates there are 2 responses to ff:dd and 48000 is the 6th column value of the request corresponding to ff:dd. I hope you understood the question. Please ask for any clarifications.
For io:uv, since there are no responses, 1 indicates number of requests, 0 indicates number of responses and 56000 is the 6th column value for this request.
I am doing all this to analyze network traffic.

I don't know how to dynamically add the values. If there are  fixed number of values, i can manage, but this is a tricky situation. I a using python2.6.  Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you tag this both `2.7` and `3.x`?

Comment: Woof do we have some data structure problems. Let me take a crack at it...

Comment: What do the fifth and sixth column values represent? Seems meaningless from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary with keys being strings and the values being a tuple containing (requests, responses, 6th column, [list of response keys])

Comment: You can't assign to tuple items. A list instead of a tuple would work fine.

Comment: @2rs2ts A list within a tuple can be assigned to.

Comment: Yes, but the requests/responses can be incremented, to my understanding at least.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make sure first that we are clear about what a dictionary is and what it can be used for (and hope I don't put my foot in my mouth - I am fairly new to Python myself).

### About Dictionaries

In Python, a `dict` maps *single keys* to *single values*. You can [read the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) if you want, but one issue here is that you seem to want to map a single key to multiple values in your desired result:

```
{'ff:dd': 1, 2, 48000, qw:er, xc:sd}, {'io:uv': 1, 0, 56000}
```

This shows two dictionaries. Looking at the first dictionary,  `{'ff:dd': 1,` maps the key `'ff:dd'` to the value `1` only; the comma says, move on to the next `key:value` pair. So the rest is interpreted as keys `2` and `48000` mapped to no values (throws `SyntaxError`), and undefined names `qw` and `xc` mapped to undefined names `er` and `sd` (would throw `NameError` if you got that far). You probably meant for `qw:er` and `xc:sd` to be strings, in which case they would be seen as keys that are not mapped to any value , like the numbers `2` and `48000` before them. You can test this out in the shell:

```
>>> {'key':'value'}               # A dict with one key, that has a value
{'key': 'value'}

>>> {'key'}                       # Curly braces can make a dict or a set
set(['key'])

>>> {'key1':'val1', 'key2'}       # A dict needs to have values for each key
SyntaxError: invalid syntax       

>>> {'key1':'val1', 'key2':}      # Even an "empty" value has to be explicit
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you did for some reason want to define your keys before you know their values, it could be workable to use a zero or empty string, but the "correct" way to do it is probably to use `dict.fromkeys()` :

```
>>> {'key1':None, 'key2':'', 'key3':0}     # One of these might do the job...
{'key3': 0, 'key2': '', 'key1': None}

>>> dict.fromkeys(['key1','key2', 'key3']) # ...but this is probably better.
{'key3': None, 'key2': None, 'key1': None}
```

(As a side note, you probably don't want to talk about "appending" to a dictionary. That's something you would do with an ordered list, e.g. by `mylist.append(myvalue)`. There is no `append()` method for a dictionary; what you do is set a key, and if the key doesn't exist, it is created. "Append" means adding to the end, but dictionaries are unordered so they have no "end" as such.)

### Storing Your Data

Now I'm going to make an assumption about what you're trying to do with `qw:er, xc:sd`, because it's not totally clear about your question. My assumption is that you simply want to have a list of the responses that were sent to `'ff:dd'`. If you wanted, you can do other things, but with that assumption I'll try to shed some light on how to do something like what you want to do. It looks like your desired result is something like:

```
traffic = { 'ff:dd': { 'reqfrom':1, 'respto':2, 'reqvals':[48000],
                       'responders':['qw:er', 'xc:sd'] },
            'io:uv': { 'reqfrom':1, 'respto':0, 'reqvals':[56000],
                       'responders':[] }
           }
```

At the top level of the `traffic` dictionary, there are two keys: `'ff:dd'` and `'io:uv'`. The value of each key is another dictionary, so that you can access the number of requests from a key, responses to a key, and other values associated with that particular address, as follows:

```
>>> traffic['io:uv']['reqfrom']         # How many requests from 'io:uv'?
1

>>> traffic['ff:dd']['responders']      # What are the responses to 'ff:dd'?
['qw:er', 'xc:sd']
```

So, how do you dynamically store these values? Normally, you would simply assign a value to a key, like `mydict['key'] = 'value'`. The value of the key will be updated if the key already exists; if not, the key-value pair will be added to the dictionary. But since the values of your first keys are themselves dictionaries, it's a bit trickier.

### Try this...

Here's an example of one possible approach, using the above assumed structure. I won't go into too much detail because more experienced Python users can probably show you better ways to do the same thing. Try this code on for size - run it, read it, break it, etc. You should be able to figure out how to adapt it for your purposes.

```
traffic = {}

packets = (('0.000', 'ff:dd', 'ff:ff', '4', '126', '48000'),
           ('0.001', 'sd:fg', 'er:sd', '5', '125', '67000'),
           ('0.002', 'qw:er', 'ff:dd', '5', '127', '90000'),
           ('0.003', 'xc:sd', 'ff:dd', '5', '127', '90000'),
           ('0.004', 'io:uv', 'gh:ij', '4', '126', '56000'))

def record_packet(packet):
    if packet[3] == '4':        # Request

        # Set up the key-value if it doesn't exist
        if packet[1] not in traffic:
            traffic[packet[1]] = {'reqfrom':0,
                                  'respto':0,
                                  'reqvals':[],
                                  'responders':[]
                                  }

        traffic[packet[1]]['reqfrom'] += 1
        traffic[packet[1]]['reqvals'].append(packet[5])

    elif packet[3] == '5':      # Response

        # Record the response IFF there has been a request
        if packet[2] in traffic:
            traffic[packet[2]]['respto'] += 1
            traffic[packet[2]]['responders'].append(packet[1])

    else:
        # Handle weirdness here
        pass

for packet in packets:
    record_packet(packet)

for key in traffic:
    for item in traffic[key]:
        print "traffic['{0}']['{1}'] has value: {2}".format(key, item, traffic[key][item])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a data structure which makes things easier.

If I understand you correctly, you'd like these addresses to be the keys of your dictionary, and you'd like the data stored under these keys to be:

- The number of requests sent from this address
- The number of requests received at this address
- A list of addresses which sent requests to this address

This would probably best be formatted like so:

```
{address:[sent, recv, [address, address, ...]], ...}
```

So, you may read the text file like so:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    dct = {}
    for line in myfile:
        splt = line.split()
```

Now you are iterating over every line in the file and splitting it by the columns. Next, we'd like to determine if it was a request or a response:

```
        if splt[3] == '4': # request
            # we're about to fill this in
        elif split[3] == '5': # response
            # we're about to fill this in
```

This checks the 4th column for either `'4'` or `'5'`. You will run into problems if you have another value there (i.e. you have poorly formatted data).

Now, if we are handling a request, we'd do the following:

```
            if splt[1] not in dct:
                dct[splt[1]] = [1, 0, []]
            else:
                dct[splt[1]][0] += 1
```

This increments the number of requests sent by 1; if the address is not in the dictionary yet, then we add it. We use `splt[1]` here because we are talking about the sender's address, not the receiver's.

If we are handling a response, we'd act differently, of course. I am assuming here that you will never send a response without a request first being made... but just in case, I've put that case in there, with `pass` to just ignore it. It's up to you to figure out what you want to do with that...

```
            if splt[2] not in dct:
                pass
            else:
                dct[splt[2]][1] += 1
                if splt[1] not in dct[splt[2]][2]:
                    dct[splt[2]][2].append(splt[1])
```

Here, we increment the number of responses received by 1, and add the responder's address to our list. We use `splt[2]` as the key instead because we are talking about the receiver's address, not the sender's.

This ought to be the crux for what you are trying to accomplish - although I don't understand what the fourth and fifth columns do, so I've omitted them.